# Remove or Find an object with Mongoose when it is in an array by the object property value

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

This is what the data looks like for an entity called "Project"

`{
  systems:[
    {
     systemId: 1234,
     count: 3 
     },
    {
     systemId: 87642,
     count: 2 
     }
  ]
}`

What I want to is find in Projects collection all projects that have in `systems` an object with the `systemId` of 1234.

Please note that systems is an `Array`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should so something like

```
Project.find({'systems':{$elemMatch:{'systemId':1234}}})
```

Comment: You mean $elemMatch not $elementMatch. $elemMatch worked for finding

Comment: yeap is $elemMatch sorry for the typo

Comment: How about if I wanted to update and $pull is it basically the same syntax?